# InterpolatedUniveriateSpline and interp1d cubic splines not passing through all points for very small y values?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I've been looking at smoothing some probability density Functions (PDFs) using cubic splines in scipy and I'm having issues with either `scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` or `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` not going through all the knots when I have small values of y.

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline, interp1d


def main():
    breadth = 0.60
    stepsize = 0.01
    mean = 0.0
    stdev = 0.02

    steps = 2. * breadth / stepsize + 1
    retRange = np.linspace(-breadth, breadth, num=steps)
    probs = {}
    for ret in retRange:
        retup = ret + stepsize / 2.
        retdown = ret - stepsize / 2.
        probup = norm.cdf(retup, loc=mean, scale=stdev)
        probdown = norm.cdf(retdown, loc=mean, scale=stdev)
        prob = probup - probdown
        probs[ret] = prob
    probs = pd.Series(probs, name='PDF')
    probs = probs / probs.sum()

    spl = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(probs.index, probs, k=3, ext='zeros')
    tmp = pd.Series(index=retRange, data=retRange, name='SmoothedPDF').map(spl)

    out = pd.concat([probs, tmp], axis=1)
    out['diff'] = out['PDF'] - out['SmoothedPDF']
    print out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The issue is that the output DataFrame shows differences. I can substitute `interp1d` instead of `InterpolateUnivariateSpline` and get the same issue (though with different results). The issue is notable in that the difference in interpolated y-value at the knot point can be larger than the original y-value.

```
                 PDF   SmoothedPDF          diff
-0.60  8.670691e-195 -2.650272e-50  2.650272e-50
-0.59  2.245130e-188  2.120217e-49 -2.120217e-49
-0.58  4.528786e-182 -9.806006e-49  9.806006e-49
-0.57  7.116703e-176  3.816392e-48 -3.816392e-48
-0.56  8.712391e-170 -1.431147e-47  1.431147e-47
-0.55  8.309255e-164  5.342948e-47 -5.342948e-47
-0.54  6.173881e-158 -1.994065e-46  1.994065e-46
-0.53  3.573809e-152  7.441963e-46 -7.441963e-46
-0.52  1.611710e-146 -2.777379e-45  2.777379e-45
-0.51  5.662799e-141  1.036532e-44 -1.036532e-44
-0.50  1.550138e-135 -3.868390e-44  3.868390e-44
-0.49  3.306066e-130  1.443703e-43 -1.443703e-43
-0.48  5.493659e-125 -5.387972e-43  5.387972e-43
-0.47  7.112603e-120  2.010818e-42 -2.010818e-42
-0.46  7.174975e-115 -7.504477e-42  7.504477e-42
-0.45  5.639566e-110  2.800709e-41 -2.800709e-41
-0.44  3.453932e-105 -1.045239e-40  1.045239e-40
-0.43  1.648294e-100  3.900884e-40 -3.900884e-40
-0.42   6.129407e-96 -1.455830e-39  1.455830e-39
-0.41   1.776139e-91  5.433231e-39 -5.433231e-39
-0.40   4.010714e-87 -2.027709e-38  2.027709e-38
-0.39   7.057745e-83  7.567514e-38 -7.567514e-38
-0.38   9.678846e-79 -2.824235e-37  2.824235e-37
-0.37   1.034450e-74  1.054019e-36 -1.054019e-36
-0.36   8.616667e-71 -3.933652e-36  3.933652e-36
-0.35   5.594107e-67  1.468059e-35 -1.468059e-35
-0.34   2.830755e-63 -5.478870e-35  5.478870e-35
-0.33   1.116539e-59  2.044742e-34 -2.044742e-34
-0.32   3.432949e-56 -7.631082e-34  7.631082e-34
-0.31   8.228222e-53  2.847958e-33 -2.847958e-33
...              ...           ...           ...
 0.31   0.000000e+00 -7.461634e-41  7.461634e-41
 0.32   0.000000e+00 -3.730817e-41  3.730817e-41
 0.33   0.000000e+00 -5.022254e-42  5.022254e-42
 0.34   0.000000e+00  3.407958e-42 -3.407958e-42
 0.35   0.000000e+00  8.968310e-43 -8.968310e-43
 0.36   0.000000e+00 -2.578389e-43  2.578389e-43
 0.37   0.000000e+00 -1.177091e-43  1.177091e-43
 0.38   0.000000e+00  9.809089e-45 -9.809089e-45
 0.39   0.000000e+00 -3.152922e-45  3.152922e-45
 0.40   0.000000e+00 -4.816963e-46  4.816963e-46
 0.41   0.000000e+00 -6.568587e-47  6.568587e-47
 0.42   0.000000e+00  4.926440e-47 -4.926440e-47
 0.43   0.000000e+00  9.579189e-48 -9.579189e-48
 0.44   0.000000e+00  3.763253e-48 -3.763253e-48
 0.45   0.000000e+00  5.131708e-49 -5.131708e-49
 0.46   0.000000e+00 -1.924391e-49  1.924391e-49
 0.47   0.000000e+00 -1.603659e-49  1.603659e-49
 0.48   0.000000e+00 -2.405488e-50  2.405488e-50
 0.49   0.000000e+00 -1.202744e-50  1.202744e-50
 0.50   0.000000e+00 -1.586954e-51  1.586954e-51
 0.51   0.000000e+00 -2.923336e-52  2.923336e-52
 0.52   0.000000e+00 -3.132146e-53  3.132146e-53
 0.53   0.000000e+00  2.610122e-54 -2.610122e-54
 0.54   0.000000e+00  3.915183e-54 -3.915183e-54
 0.55   0.000000e+00 -1.631326e-54  1.631326e-54
 0.56   0.000000e+00 -1.386627e-54  1.386627e-54
 0.57   0.000000e+00 -2.650905e-55  2.650905e-55
 0.58   0.000000e+00  1.835242e-55 -1.835242e-55
 0.59   0.000000e+00  4.078315e-56 -4.078315e-56
 0.60   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00

[121 rows x 3 columns]
```

And yes, I'm working on some things that involve very low probabilities hence the scale really is (sometimes) that small.

I can do some rescaling if it's a precision issue, but before doing so I'd like to confirm that's the issue.

As a side note, using linear interpolate (k=1) doesn't show this issue.

Comment: Can you normalize your values to around 1, for fitting purposes. Some algorithms just get messed up under the hood. Normalizing the input values can help.

Comment: Given the range of values (1e-195 to 1e-53, at least), perhaps using a logarithmic scale (also) helps?

Comment: @Evert I can do some scaling, but the PDF is already normalized to a sum of 1 (these are fairly narrow distributions relative to the x-axis range) so I can't easily normalize the whole set. What I can do is floor() values (giving up some precision in the tails), effectively narrowing the x-values ranges. I'd prefer not to do that since some of the values of interest are in the tails.

Comment: I mean to normalise your data for just the fit, then scale the results back to the actual values (so you need to keep the normalisation factor). That shouldn't matter then for the PDF, just the fitting.

Comment: @Evert Ah...gotcha. Seems like a good idea to try out...I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the spline interpolator you're trying to use interpolates globally, which is a very bad fit for your input. Due to the exponential cut-off, a lot of your values are exactly zero due to double precision; in this range the spline interpolators give you noise.

Here's a numerical representation of the problem, by plotting your PDF and its spline interpolant on a semilog scale (note that where the PDF is exactly zero you get missing points in the log plot):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(out.index, out.PDF, 'r-', out.index, out.SmoothedPDF.abs(), 'bo--',
             markerfacecolor='none') # note the abs for log
plt.legend(['PDF', 'SmoothedPDF (univariate spline)'])
plt.show()
```

[image: good match in range where the original value is above 1e-30, very bad otherwise]

Firstly, I needed to call `.abs()` on the interpolated values in order to plot the *negative* ones (we're interpolating a nonzero function!). Secondly, as I already noted, the range above x=0.2 should be missing, since the function values are exactly zero here. Instead we have noise of the order of 1e-50, just like on the small-x limit. Altogether what we can see is that where your data is smaller than 1e-30 you don't stand a chance.

My first idea was to use `griddata`, but it shows similarly bad results (even though the numeric error is much smaller in that case). So how about using a *local* interpolator? Enter the [piecewise cubic Hermite spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.pchip_interpolate.html). With a slightly modified version of your code, to demonstrate both interpolation and numerical stability:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.interpolate import pchip_interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    breadth = 0.60
    stepsize = 0.01
    mean = 0.0
    stdev = 0.02

    steps = 2. * breadth / stepsize + 1
    bigRange = np.linspace(-breadth, breadth, num=5*steps)
    retRange = bigRange[::5]
    probs = {}
    for ret in retRange:
        retup = ret + stepsize / 2.
        retdown = ret - stepsize / 2.
        probup = norm.cdf(retup, loc=mean, scale=stdev)
        probdown = norm.cdf(retdown, loc=mean, scale=stdev)
        prob = probup - probdown
        probs[ret] = prob
    probs = pd.Series(probs, name='PDF')
    probs = probs / probs.sum()

    tmp_big = pd.Series(index=bigRange,
                  data=pchip_interpolate(probs.index.values, probs.values, bigRange),
                  name='SmoothedPDF_big') # denser interpolated case
    tmp_check = pd.Series(index=retRange,
                    data=pchip_interpolate(probs.index.values, probs.values, retRange),
                    name='SmoothedPDF') # base points for checking stability

    out = pd.concat([probs, tmp_check], axis=1)
    out['diff'] = out['PDF'] - out['SmoothedPDF']

    return out,tmp_big

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    out,pchipout = main()
    plt.figure()
    plt.semilogy(out.index, out.PDF, 'r-', pchipout.index, pchipout.abs().values, 'bo--',
                 markerfacecolor='none')
    plt.legend(['PDF', 'SmoothedPDF (piecewise cubic Hermit spline)'])

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(out.index, out.PDF, 'r-', pchipout.index, pchipout.values, 'bo--',
             markerfacecolor='none')
    plt.legend(['PDF', 'SmoothedPDF (piecewise cubic Hermit spline)'])


    plt.show()
```

Proof of stability:

```
>>> out['diff'].any()
False
```

Logarithmic plot for error scale:

[image: plot with PCHIP spline: very nice agreement, negligible error at 1e-180 value]

As you can see, the agreement is almost perfect. Note the distinct lack of values where your original data is exactly 0. What noise remains below values of 1e-100 on the small-x range you'll have to learn live with.

Actual plot of the interpolated result:

[image: interpolated figure on a lin scale]

Comment: I believe local interpolation ends up with continuous first derivatives at the knots but doesn't guarantee continuous higher order derivatives? Just checking (these PDFs are used for some work later and continuous second derivatives are very helpful in those steps), as the providing continuous first derivatives is likely sufficient!

Comment: @Dori I'm afraid it's been a while since I was formally taught interpolation methods; I'll look into it and get back to you :)

Comment: @DoriLevanoni OK, this wasn't too hard considering it's [documented](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator): "*The first derivatives are guaranteed to be continuous, but the second derivatives may jump at `x_k`*". Also "*The interpolator preserves monotonicity in the interpolation data and does not overshoot if the data is not smooth*" might be non-trivial information for you, considering how your data is very sharply peaked.